# How to display error to the user in MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, mern

I got node/express api with mongoDB connected and react/redux on front-end.

How could I display errors (for example with database connection) to the user.

For example if error occurs on backend and I want to create big  tag with error message in component?

Answer (score 4):

This article show point you the right direction. I had to search for this as well:

https://itnext.io/javascript-error-handling-from-express-js-to-react-810deb5e5e28

to access error message, try this if you are using Axios...

```
try{
// something...
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error.response.data)
}
```